# REST API return null in if-else condition

Tags: php

I am trying to consume REST API service and check if the parameter coming exist in some tables.

Scenarios:

1. Check if the value exist in the license table,
2. If not, check the license used table
3. if not in either of the table then it does not exist; print out an error message

My problem:

If I use just **if-else**, it works but if I include the **else if** it returns **null**

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```php
<?php
    header("Content-Type:application/json");

    //if (isset($_GET['licence']) && $_GET['licence']!="") {

    $licence = $_GET['licence'];

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, licence, 
        period, users FROM licence WHERE licence='$licence'");

    $counts = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($counts>0) {
        // get retrieved row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            // create array
            $user_arr=array(
                "status" => true,
                "message" => "Successfully Validated!",
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "licence" => $row['licence'],
                "period" => $row['period'],
                "user" => $row['users'],
                "mstatus" => $row['status']
            );
        }
    } elseif ($counts==0) {
        $querys = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
            COUNT(licence) num,   
            licence, period, users FROM licence_used 
            WHERE licence='$licence'");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($querys);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($querys);

        if ($count > 0) {

            if ($row['num'] == $row['users']) {
                $user_arr=array(
                    "status" => false,
                    "message" => "Licence key entered has been used by ".$row['users']." users. Please purchase another licence.",
                );
            } else {

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($querys)){
                    // create array
                    $user_arr=array(
                        "status" => true,
                        "message" => "Successfully Validated!",
                        "id" => $row['id'],
                        "licence" => $row['licence'],
                        "period" => $row['period'],
                        "user" => $row['users'],
                        "mstatus" => $row['status']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $user_arr=array(
            "status" => false,
            "message" => "Invalid Licence Key Entered. Please contact the software company.",
        );
    }

    // make it json format
    print_r(json_encode($user_arr));

    //} 

?>
```

Comment: You have completely changed the logic so now you will only get the Invalid Licence Key message if your $count from your first query is a negative number.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, But I thought it should execute what is inside the elseif if it doesn't meet the first condition.

Comment: It does, but once you are in there, the only way you will get a response is if a license exists in license_old. Otherwise nothing happens. I think you need to format your code and read it to see what is happening. Effectively you have removed any action in the case where there is no match in license or license_old.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice not avoid nesting so many ifs/elses, it makes the code harder to read and debug.

The last else is unreachable and there is no way the total results will be < 0

You could also split the cases in functions and call them accordingly, another good way to make the code readable.

I did some changes to your code as an example, code looks awful in here so I used pastebin instead.

https://pastebin.com/wuryVaph

(I had to include some code because stackoverflow demands that in order to use the pastebin, but ignore this if you want to, is a recommended function to print the results).

```
<?php

header("Content-Type:application/json");

function reply($reply){

    print json_encode($reply);
    exit;

}
```

I hope it helps.